# drools workbench with jbpm-server-7.73.0.Final-dist file from jbpmn.org site

Tags: wildfly, drools, jbpm, workbench, kie

After downloading jbpm-server-7.73.0.Final-dist.zip and running standalone.bat file facing issue in startup of server as deployment is not completed

I want to fix this issue to get server up an running properly so that Drools workbench functionalities can be tested.

```
18:43:58,500 ERROR [ErraiMarshalling] (MSC service thread 1-4) null
18:43:58,505 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
18:43:58,503 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke void org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.postConstruct() on org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl@516ad408
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:38)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:505)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:98)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke void org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.postConstruct() on org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl@516ad408
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:174)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:140)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:102)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:196)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:187)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
        at javax.enterprise.api//javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:83)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.backend.server.io.object.ObjectStorageImpl.initializeMarshaller(ObjectStorageImpl.java:122)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.backend.server.io.object.ObjectStorageImpl.init(ObjectStorageImpl.java:44)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigStorageImpl.setup(SpaceConfigStorageImpl.java:80)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigStorageRegistryImpl.lambda$get$0(SpaceConfigStorageRegistryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigStorageRegistryImpl.get(SpaceConfigStorageRegistryImpl.java:52)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigStorageRegistryImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.get(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.getAllOrganizationalUnits(OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl.java:203)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.OrganizationalUnitServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getAllOrganizationalUnits(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.isArchetypesOUAvailable(ArchetypeServiceImpl.java:726)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.maybeCreateArchetypesOU(ArchetypeServiceImpl.java:693)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.postConstruct(ArchetypeServiceImpl.java:165)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: critical problem loading the marshallers
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton.<clinit>(MappingContextSingleton.java:94)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton$4.<init>(MappingContextSingleton.java:190)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton.loadDynamicMarshallers(MappingContextSingleton.java:189)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.MappingContextSingleton.<clinit>(MappingContextSingleton.java:84)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.exceptions.InvalidMappingException: there is no custom mapping or default no-arg constructor to map: org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftdouble.HardSoftDoubleScore
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactorySingleton.<clinit>(DefinitionsFactorySingleton.java:32)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.exceptions.InvalidMappingException: there is no custom mapping or default no-arg constructor to map: org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftdouble.HardSoftDoubleScore
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.api.impl.defaultjava.DefaultJavaDefinitionMapper.map(DefaultJavaDefinitionMapper.java:167)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactoryImpl.loadCustomMappings(DefinitionsFactoryImpl.java:383)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactoryImpl.<init>(DefinitionsFactoryImpl.java:126)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactorySingleton.newInstance(DefinitionsFactorySingleton.java:41)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.jboss.errai.marshalling.rebind.DefinitionsFactorySingleton.<clinit>(DefinitionsFactorySingleton.java:26)
        ... 58 more

18:43:58,535 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "business-central.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"business-central.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke void org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.postConstruct() on org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl@516ad408
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke void org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.postConstruct() on org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl@516ad408
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: critical problem loading the marshallers
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.exceptions.InvalidMappingException: there is no custom mapping or default no-arg constructor to map: org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftdouble.HardSoftDoubleScore
    Caused by: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.exceptions.InvalidMappingException: there is no custom mapping or default no-arg constructor to map: org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftdouble.HardSoftDoubleScore"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Our company started using jbpm 7.73 recently and found that it does not run with the latest version of java 11 runtime that some developers had installed. We had to use an older java 11 runtime to get it to work. Not sure if we got the same error as you were seeing but it might be worth trying if you have not fixed your issue. Currently using this version which works.

openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20

OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the main reason, it started to be broken with openjdk 11.0.16
We know that the latest working openjdk JRE is 11.0.15. The main problem is probably outdated Wildfly and a JDK change which impacts deployment.